# Option Base 1 Triggering Errors When Exporting to Excel from Sharepoint

Tags: excel, listobject, vba

I am currently exporting a Sharepoint list to Excel 2013 but noticed that the export throws a 'Subscript out of range' error whenever I specify Option Base 1 at the top of my module. When I remove Option Base 1, the macro runs nominally. My guess is that this may have to do with the enumeration of the list being imported and the 0th element not being recognized. My questions are: a) Does anyone know why this occurs, if not for the reason I guessed? and b) If there's a way to retain Option Base 1 without throwing an error upon the import? Code:

```
Option Base 1

Sub Sharepoint_Import()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim objMyList As ListObject
Dim objWksheet As Worksheet
Const SERVER As String = "https://xxxx/_vti_bin"

Const LISTNAME As String = "{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"
Const VIEWNAME As String = "{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}"

Set objWksheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

'Clear older data on Sheet "Data"
objWksheet.UsedRange.ClearContents
objWksheet.UsedRange.ClearFormats

'Import data
Set objMyList = objWksheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Array(SERVER, LISTNAME, VIEWNAME), True, , Range("A1"))

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: It has to do with [.Net deprecating Option Base](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk5ash0b(v=vs.90).aspx). The ListObject object is 0 based by default and is unaffected by your your `Option Base 1` declaration. I'm not sure of a way around this...maybe assign the SP list to a variant array and then the array to your listobect?

Comment: Sounds like a good plan. I'll give it a shot, thanks